# What does the `this@classname` mean in Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, this

I am making a custom view for Android.
I am going to clone the layout by calling clone (`this`), but it shows error, when I use clone (`this@mycustomclassname`), it works.

It's still confused. Anyone knows the meaning of `this@classname` in kotlin?

Comment: Pretty much same as `MainActivity.this` in Java

Answer (score 21, accepted):

This is a [qualified `this`](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/this-expressions.html). You can access `this` from an outer scope.

As `this` can mean different things (part the referenced page):

> To denote the current receiver, we use this expressions:
>
> - In a member of a class, this refers to the current object of that class.
> - In an extension function or a function literal with receiver this denotes the receiver parameter that is passed on the left-hand side of
>     a dot.